# loop over many files and plot them

Tags: python, loops, csv

Thanks for the time spending reading it, maybe it is a simple question.
I have a file like this (they are like 200 files):

```
    Output of SMC2FS2: FAS for file 20123427.CB2A.BHE.sac.smc
 Nfreq_out = 
   8192
           freq            fas
  0.0000000E+00  6.6406252E-03
  2.4414062E-03  1.3868844E+04
  4.8828125E-03  3.0740834E+04
  7.3242188E-03  2.7857139E+04
  9.7656250E-03  1.6535047E+04
  1.2207031E-02  9.7825762E+03
  1.4648438E-02  6.1421987E+03
  1.7089844E-02  6.5783145E+03
  1.9531250E-02  5.6137949E+03
  2.1972656E-02  3.5297178E+03
```

To read them, to skip the header and to start the processing:

```
#define the path where I have the 200 files
pato='D:\\Seismic_Inves\\flc_grant\\120427\\smc2fs\\smooth'
os.chdir(pato)
lista=[]
#list all files with "kono_" 
for a in glob.glob('*kono_*'):
    lista.append(a)
#read and skip the header for all files
for archis in lista:
    with open(archis,'r') as leo:
       for _ in range(4):
            next(leo)
#start the proccesing
       for line in leo:
           leo=[x.strip() for x in leo if x.strip()]
           leos=[tuple(map(float,x.split())) for x in leo[1:]]
           f=[x[0] for x in leos]
           fas=[x[1] for x in leos]
           plt.figure(1)
           plt.plot(f,fas,'r')
           plt.yscale('log')
           plt.xscale('log')
           plt.show()
```

As you can imagine it is a plot of Frequency vs Amplitude (FAS plot)
The code works well, but open a figure and plot just one file, then I need to close the figure and it will plot the second file and so on.

The question is:

> How can I plot all the data (the 200 fcsv iles)  in just one figure.
>
> to @GlobalTraveler, this is the result using your suggestion:

[FAS Konoomachi_smooth_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7yWH.png)

Comment: Since I didn't have the data, this is what you wanted yes?

Comment: @GlobalTraveler Yes, it was I wnated, FAS plot for seismic station and their behaivor, all of them with Konoomachi smoothing technique.

Comment: Not sure what kind of smoothing that is. Regardless, can you mark the question as answered? If you have any further questions just shoot me a message.

Comment: @GlobalTraveler, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the  block argument to show -> plt.show(block = False) or move show outside the for loop

However in the grandscheme of things I would suggest moving the code to more OO approach. For example:

```
#define the path where I have the 200 files
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, show
pato='D:\\Seismic_Inves\\flc_grant\\120427\\smc2fs\\smooth'
os.chdir(pato)
lista=[]
#list all files with "kono_" 
for a in glob.glob('*kono_*'):
    lista.append(a)
#read and skip the header for all files

fig, ax  = subplots() # open figure and create axis
for archis in lista:
    with open(archis,'r') as leo:
       for _ in range(4):
            next(leo)
#start the proccesing
       for line in leo:
           leo=[x.strip() for x in leo if x.strip()]
           leos=[tuple(map(float,x.split())) for x in leo[1:]]
           f=[x[0] for x in leos]
           fas=[x[1] for x in leos]
           ax.plot(f,fas,'r') # plot on this axis
ax.set(**dict(xscale = 'log', yscale = 'log')) # format the axis
show() # show
```

it is the result with your suggestion
[FAS_konoomachi_smooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXCz0.png)

Comment: I agree with O.O. Programing, it is better to work subplots()